# Github - error: src refspec main does not match any

Tags: git, github

Estoy haciendo algo muy simple pero me sale un error que nunca me salió:

1. Hago `git remote add origin` https://github.com/maurimoma/rock_paper_scissors.git.
2. Hago `$ git push -u origin main` y me sale el error
3. En `$ git remote -v` me muestra esto

   ```
   origin  https://github.com/maurimoma/rock_paper_scissors.git (fetch)
   origin  https://github.com/maurimoma/rock_paper_scissors.git (push)
   ```

Comment: Estás tratando de empujar tu rama local `main` al repositorio `origin`... _pero_ esa rama no existe en tu repositorio local. Verifica las ramas que tienes en el local usando `git branch`.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias, lo pruebo

Comment: Listo, resuelto, tal cual: lo resolví con el comando "git config global...." Gracias

Comment: No me suena que `git config global....` vaya a ayudar en tu situación particular _pero_ si ya lo resolviste, me alegro.